# Cheerio weird parsing

Tags: cheerio

I am testing with very simple code:

```
const $ = await cheerio.load("<body> <table> kokoko </table> </body>");
await console.log($("body").first().html());
```

But when I run it I get this in console:

```
kokoko<table></table>
```

Why is the `kokoko` outside of `<table>` tag?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `<table>` element cannot directly contain text content, it would need to be inside `<tr>` and `<td>` or `<th>` elements.

The parser is therefore interpreting the text as being directly in the `<body>`, the closest location where it's allowed.

Comment: I see so it's trying to be smart. Do you know any other parse which is not so smart? I need that one

Comment: @cikatomo You might be better off using an XML parser, which doesn't know about the semantics of different HTML elements; but then you'll have the opposite problem with things that aren't valid XML, like `hello <br> world`.